# How do I migrate to hashed Firebase passwords?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I have an existing client, which calls a server, which in turn calls

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword
```

With that, client POSTs to the server (and server, to Firebase) an unhashed password over HTTPS.

I would like to salt/hash the password on the client. I am at liberty to use the same algorithm Firebase uses. But I don't see a method for sending a hashed password to Firebase. And I have existing users who, of course, can't lose access with this migration.

Answer (score 2):

To sign in to Firebase Authentication's email/password provider, you have to send the password in cleartext over a secure connection. There is no way to change this.

This is not a security risk to send the password in cleartext, as the secure connection is end-to-end encrypted, so the only two sides who can see the data can already access it anyway. If somebody can intercept the data and decrypt it, it means they have access to the certificate of your secure connection, which is a much broader security risk.

Of you want to sign in with a password in a different form, the only way to do that is by [implementing your own custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) on top of Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Wow, an answer from a Google Cloud employee, at odd hours and within 8 minutes! That's awesome.

Comment: I wouldn't entirely agree that there is no security risk. Sure, encryption prevents man in the middle attacks, but the fact that the password  lives in cleartext on the server, and lives in cleartext on the client longer than it has to, these are both vectors of attack. However small.

Comment: Also, it's debatable what's a broader security risk: someone gaining access to one fairly obscure server, or to user credentials to all servers.

Comment: The password is not stored in cleartext on the server. It exists there in cleartext during transmission, but is salted and hashed before being stored. Sorry if my answer seemed to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear. We have 3 units: 1) my client, 2) my auth server, 3) firebase. I don't want my auth server to handle a cleartext password, even transiently, unless I have to. But like you said, it's not a big deal.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that part indeed, so would recommend (also) editing your question to clarify. In your current approach there's no way to prevent the password from reaching your own server in an unencrypted form. I'd recommend leaving it to the Firebase SDK on the client to sign in in, and (if needed) pass the ID token from the client to your own server where you can then verify it and act based on the user's identity.